# Missing template argument before

Tags: c++, regex, string

I am trying to get a sub-string enclosed inside a string using regex but seem to be getting the following error:

```
//code
#include <regex>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){

string str1="hello \"trimthis\" please";
regex rgx("\"([^\"]*)\""); // will capture "trimthis"
regex_iterator current(str1.begin(), str1.end(), rgx);
regex_iterator end;
while (current != end)
    cout << *current++; 
return 0;
}
```

//errors
missing template arguments before 'current'

missing template arguments before 'end'

'current' was not declared in this scope

Is there a different syntax to what I'm trying to do because I haven't used regex before and kind of a newbie to c++

Comment: Post full code, and separate it from the errors, and you somehow left out the line numbers etc that the compiler would've given you for those.

Comment: Even with `string str1="hello \"trimthis\" please";` the errors persist. You may use https://ideone.com/H5YXNt if you plan to get several matches.

Comment: `regex_iterator` is a class template. You need to use `sregex_iterator`. Please take a look at the example code at http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/regex_iterator.

Comment: @RSahu get the following error after using sregex_iterator: cannot bind 'std::ostream {aka std::basic_ostream<char>}' lvalue to 'std::basic_ostream<char>&&'

Comment: @carlson.boy See the link in my comment. Do you need to get a single match or multiple matches?

Comment: @Rakete1111 sorry that was a mistake i made while typing it out here not in the actual code.

Comment: @RSahu multiple

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Problem 1

`regex_iterator` is a class template. You need to use  `sregex_iterator`.

#### Problem 2

`*current` evaluates to a `std::smatch`. There is no overload to insert such an object to a `std::ostream`. You need to use:

```
  cout << current->str();
```

---

Here's an updated version of the program that works for me.

```
//code
#include <regex>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){

   string str1="hello \"trimthis\" please";
   regex rgx("\"([^\"]*)\""); // will capture "trimthis"
   sregex_iterator current(str1.begin(), str1.end(), rgx);
   sregex_iterator end;
   while (current != end)
   {
      cout << current->str() << endl;  // Prints the entire match "trimthis"
      cout << current->str(1) << endl; // Prints the group, trimthis
      current++; 
   }
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: OP needs to obtain Group 1 value, so you should use `current->str(1)` instead of `current->str()`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, thanks for that.